# How to send a single request to a particular person in Facebook? (in FBML)

Tags: facebook, fbml

Instead of popup the multiple friend selector, how to do it only for one friend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the request-form-submit fbml tag to do this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/request-form-submit